# IMPORTHTML() in GoogleSheet is giving empty table

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to import data from a table within an HTML page. I tried IMPORTHTML("**[https://www.sharesansar.com/proposed-dividend**","table",4](https://www.sharesansar.com/proposed-dividend**%22,%22table%22,4))but it doesn't work.

After inspection of the page, I found table is being feed using JavaScript and JSON object. I know this table or the whole JSON can be fetched to googlesheet using Google App Script but I don't know how to do it?

Can anyone help me with writing the script function for this?